# Java - String.format with hyphen

Tags: java

Writing my first real bit of Java code and I'm struggling to figure out this one out.

I need to generate a string in set format:

```
code:100-100-100
```

I'm using String.format to try and generate it:

```
String templateFormat = "code:%1$-%2$s-100";
String code = String.format(templateFormat, "100", "100", "100");
```

But the hyphen has special meaning to the formatter, how can I escape it?

Tried to escape the hyphen with a "\" but Eclipse rightly informed me:

Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )

Cheers

Comment: What actually gets printed out?

Comment: "that didn't work" is completely unhelpful.  When posting a problem, please post the exact error message or actual output you saw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't with your hyphen so much as with your templateFormat:

You have... `String templateFormat = "code:%1$-%2$s-100";`

Where you need... `String templateFormat = "code:%1$s-%2$s-100";`

Notice the missing `s` in the `%1$` part

Comment: To answer another part of your question - the hyphen has special meaning in a format when to the left of a number (left-justify); otherwise it does NOT have a special meaning and won't interfere with output.  Be sure to accept and perhaps upvote this (and any) answer that solves your problem.

Comment: Many thanks. The missing "s" was the problem - as you've pointed out, the hyphen does NOT need escaping in my example.